# What is the dimension of a heap?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Heap is a kind of data structure used in computer science. 
But what is it dimension?
An array can be 1-D 2-D...etc
Young's tableaux is 2-D
But what about heaps?

Comment: I don't think this question is physics related.

Comment: it is indeed statistical mechanics, if you know enough physics.

Comment: Maybe math related.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define a dimension of a data-structure?
A heap can be stored and maintained in a 1-D array, does that mean it's 1-D?